# Why can't PageSpeed Insights see my Viewport Meta Tag?

Tags: php, html, mobile, seo

I've added the code

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

to the HEAD of my webpage the Index.php at DuchyBrass.co.uk

It is on Line 6 of the source code, but the site runs on a bespoke CMS so the HEAD is defined in its own file and imported.

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <?php include 'app/common/head.php'; ?>
    </head>
    <body>

...
```

**head.php**

```
<title>Duchy Brass</title>
<meta charset="windows-1252" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="QsU348JA47VLcAbTUic-Un90bVlGuVk3a9A34doxsvc" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Viga' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="imgs/favicon.ico">
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.duchybrass.co.uk" />
```

As far as the browser is concerned (I assume) that viewport tag is visible, but it is not seen by that Mobile SEO tool. Is this something to do with the CMS, loading the information too late, or is this a common issue that I should ignore?

The top of my Index page (using view page source from the browser) looks like

**/ (page source)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <title>Duchy Brass</title>
        <meta charset="windows-1252" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

...
```

Comment: When you view the source of your page, do you see the viewport tag?

Comment: Yes

`code`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
 <head>
  <title>Duchy Brass</title>
<meta charset="windows-1252" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />.... `code`

Comment: The results of PageSpeed Inisights are cached for 30s. Has it been 30 seconds since your change?

Comment: Yes, I had been trying - unsuccessfully - for about two hours. I thought it might have been incorrect syntax of the tag, or maybe it had to be the first tag in the Head. All sorts of variations.

Just had a look now (roughly now, after about 17 hours) it now detects it.

So maybe it was a Cache related issue, then it seems?

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: **clear caches and check if there is no content before head** (ctrl+U)

I had a similar problem, in my case there were content being included trough PHP before my wordpress header call,
check it with Ctrl+U (see source) and be sure there is **nothing before** the

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang='en'>
      <head>
```

if you change the code and it persists, check if you're using cache, you may have to **clear caches** of pages and files so the changes take effect before running another PageSpeed analysis